#  FeatureClassNameClass.Open() Error, any ideas?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine

This code works fine on my Windows 7 64 bit machine, but fails on the target machine, Windows Server Standard SP2 64 bit.

```
 public List<string> GetShapeFileFieldNames(string shapeFileDirectory, string shapeFileName)
    {
        shapeFileName = shapeFileName.ToUpper().Replace(".LYR", ".SHP"); 

        IWorkspaceName pInShpWorkspaceName = new WorkspaceNameClass() as IWorkspaceName;
        pInShpWorkspaceName.PathName = shapeFileDirectory;
        pInShpWorkspaceName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = "esriCore.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory";
        IFeatureClassName pFCName = new FeatureClassNameClass() as IFeatureClassName;
        IDatasetName pShpDatasetName = pFCName as IDatasetName;
        pShpDatasetName.Name = shapeFileName;//this is your input file 
        pShpDatasetName.WorkspaceName = pInShpWorkspaceName;

        IName sourceName = (IName)pFCName;
        IFeatureClass sourceFeatureClass = (IFeatureClass)sourceName.Open(); //HERE IS THE ERROR
        IFields sourceFields = sourceFeatureClass.Fields;
        return GetFieldNames(sourceFields);
    }
```

Exception from HRESULT 0x80040351 
at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.FeatureClassNameClass.Open()

I converted the HRESULT into decimal, 2147746641, and ran it through Google

- 2147746641 ESRI
- 2147746641 Constants

No results.

Comment: This looks like really old code ... try replacing "esriCore" with "esriDataSourcesFile".  The progID's changed way back (at 8.3?).  Also shapeFileName doesn't need an extension.

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall I took the code from the book, "Programming ArcObjects with VBA" I guess its dated.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out. (Something cannot be found.)](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/5750-COM-Exception-was-unhandled-HRESULT-0x80040351-while-moving-data)